# PL/SQL - Returning a table from a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am creating a function that returns a table as a result. This function is basically doing comparison between two tables, and returns data set that if two tables contain different data.
**P_min_id** and **p_max_id** are ignorable, and will be implemented in the future once this function is working.
I modified the original code from http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html. The error messages are commented in the following code.

```
create or replace function return_objects(
  p_min_id in number,
  p_max_id in number
)
return t_nested_table as
  v_ret   t_nested_table;
begin
  select *              // Error(8,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
  into
    v_ret
  from 
  (
    select 
    *
    from 
    (
      select * from 
      (
        select * from SCHEMA.TEST            
        minus
        select * from SCHEMA.TEST_1
      )
      union all
      select * from
      (
        select * from SCHEMA.TEST_1
        minus
        select * from SCHEMA.TEST
      )
    )
  )
return v_ret;           

end return_objects;
```

It would be appreciated if you can fix my code, but I want to know why this code should not work. Please give me some keyword, so that I can research. or relevant website for reference would be also appreciated.

Comment: @Glenn - I assume you mean a semicolon, not a comma.  You're also missing the `bulk collect` in your `into`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a semicolon after the end of the SQL statement and use `bulk collect` to populate the nested table.  Here's a working example:

```
create or replace type t_nested_table is table of varchar2(100);

create or replace function return_objects(
  p_min_id in number,
  p_max_id in number
)
return t_nested_table as
  v_ret   t_nested_table;
begin
  select *
  bulk collect into v_ret
  from 
  (
    select 'A' from dual union all
    select 'B' from dual
  );

  return v_ret;

end;
/

select return_objects(1,2) from dual;
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the question edits there is also a privilege issue.  Your user probably has access to the tables through a role, but to create a function those privileges should be granted directly to your user.

Comment: Thank you for the answer again! I realized that privilege issue after I edited, so I removed it :) Thank you anyway!